# SetInterval() leaks memory causing problems when loading images

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, setinterval, memory-leaks

I made a flash application showing 9 rows (profile information,image) from a php script that is connected to a mysql database. This application is refreshed every 3 seconds (because it's connected to a database and this script needs to be refreshed to see any changes without refreshing the whole page)

The first problem is that if I remove this code, the images will be shown instantly but with different dimensions (this is an issue). 
If I add this part of the code, the images will be shown with the correct dimensions but they appear in 3 seconds(this is another issue).

```
clipname.Main.addChild(thumb);
clipname.Main.width=200
clipname.Main.height=200
clipname.Main.x=clipname.Main.y=60
```

What I want is that the images have to be shown instantly and with the set dimensions.

The second problem is that `SetInterval()` is leaking some memory :(

Here is my full code:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.sendToURL;
import flash.events.Event;

var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("proyectos.php");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);

var myInterval = setInterval(loadedd, 3000);
setInterval(myInterval,0);

function loadedd() {

var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("proyectos.php");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);

}

function loadCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
var variable:URLVariables=new URLVariables(e.target.data);
for (var i:int = 0; i <= 8; i++){

var clipname=this["Menuuser"+i]
this["foto"+i]=String(variable.foto[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].nombre.text=String(variable.nombre[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].nick.text=String(variable.nick[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].email.text=String(variable.email[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].aparea.text=String(variable.aparea[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].motivos.text=String(variable.motivos[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].comentario.text=String(variable.comentario[i]);
this["Menuuser"+i].fecha.text=String(variable.fecha);

var thumb:Loader = new Loader();
thumb.load(new URLRequest(this["foto"+i]));
//Here is the problem, when i put this code the images will appear in 3 seconds(i dont want that. But if i remove that part the images will be shown instantly(good) but it will appear with different dimensions(here the problem)

clipname.Main.addChild(thumb);
clipname.Main.width=200
clipname.Main.height=200
clipname.Main.x=clipname.Main.y=60

 }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done already to confirm `setInterval` is issuing a memory leak? Have you checked this with `System.totalMemory` ? Last I checked this should still be getting ran through GC.

Comment: I tested on a browser and checked it with Ctrl+Alt+Sup and the green bar of the memory was getting full. Then i close that windows and the green bar was normal. If i dont use setInterval the memory wont leak.But SetInterval is too useful to mee because it refresh the records of mysql.

Comment: Taken from adobe on setInterval:

`Instead of using the setInterval() method, consider creating a Timer object, with the specified interval, using 0 as the repeatCount parameter (which sets the timer to repeat indefinitely).

If you intend to use the clearInterval() method to cancel the setInterval() call, be sure to assign the setInterval() call to a variable (which the clearInterval() function will later reference). If you do not call the clearInterval() function to cancel the setInterval() call, the object containing the set timeout closure function will not be garbage collected.`

Comment: Bennett Yeah, i read that from adobe,  but if i use clearInterval() the autorefresh will stop working. Also i made a test of System.totalMemory and here is the results:    124768256 in 1 minute

Comment: I'll try rigging it up real fast, any qualms with using a timer instead?

Comment: How can i make a Timer Event?

Comment: I'll post it in an answer, with my results. Although this won't solve your image issue, it should still be useful

Comment: Ok, no problem, also thanks for being really helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by adobe:

*Instead of using the setInterval() method, consider creating a Timer object, with the specified interval, using 0 as the repeatCount parameter (which sets the timer to repeat indefinitely).*

*If you intend to use the clearInterval() method to cancel the setInterval() call, be sure to assign the setInterval() call to a variable (which the clearInterval() function will later reference). If you do not call the clearInterval() function to cancel the setInterval() call, the object containing the set timeout closure function will not be garbage collected.*

I ran a version of setInterval and did not find a memory leak (obviously not using `clearInterval()`)

```
private var interval:uint = setInterval( intervalTest, 3000 );
```

My results are as follows:

run 1 total memory: 3837952

run 2 total memory: 4427776

run 3 total memory: 4427776

And that continues without a memory leak. Although I'm not sure how your code is running considering this contains an error:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(loadedd, 3000);
setInterval(myInterval,0); //this line, setInterval params are function, delay, 
//you are passing setInterval "myInterval" which is actually of type uint
```

I suspect the erroneous code is where the "leak" may be coming from.

An example using a timer instead looks like this:

```
private var timer:Timer = new Timer( 3000, 0 );
timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, loadedd );
```

Then change your loadded() definition to this:

```
function loadedd( e:TimerEvent )
```

As for the issue with the images, I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Now its refreshing, i added the timer.start();   But the memory still leaking :/

Comment: Now its fixed, thanks Bennet :D, also i set the setinterval to 100 (every .1 second) and the image is shown instantly. You fixed both problems.